# structured streaming `apply` has no output

Tags: spark-structured-streaming

code:

```
df_streaming = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    ... \
    .load() \
    .xxx()

df_streaming = df_streaming \
    .groupBy(["name", "height"]) \
    .apply(cal_feature)

stream_writer = df_streaming \
    .writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .start()

stream_writer.awaitTermination()
```

`df_streaming` like this:

```
name height weight
jack 173    100
tom  175    110
tom  175    115
```

and `cal_feature`:

```
@pandas_udf(FEATURE_SCHEMA, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def cal_feature(df):
    feature_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=FEATURE_NAMES)

    feature_df["name"] = df["name"].iloc[0]
    feature_df["height"] = df["height"].iloc[0]
    feature_df["max_weight"] = df["weight"].max()
    
    # other complicated processing
    xxx...
    
    return feature_df
```

I know `agg(functions.max("weight"))` can get it, but there are other pandas functions that I want to use in `cal_feature`.

When static dataframes are used(from csv file), there is output.
agg(max) also get it, Does structured streaming dataframe support apply?

spark-2.4.5
python-3.7.10

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any proof of success with using Grouped Map Pandas UDFs on streaming aggregations in structured streaming. I recently wrote a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68114105/spark-structured-streaming-in-append-mode-outputting-many-rows-per-single-time-w) about Pandas Grouped Map UDFs in structured streaming. I have had no issue getting results/records output from a grouped map Pandas UDF in structured streaming, but many issues in having them process the correct data set and return the correct results (and not instead returning many incorrect results off partial inputs). However, my experience is limited to the Python API. Please do leave an update here if you are successful or find out more.